# How to select records without duplicates with the latest record in one field in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, distinct

I have some results from a Microsoft Access query in three columns: Publisher, Vendor, and ID.

Each publisher has titles that we purchased from different vendors over time. I would like to get a distinct list of publishers with the newest vendor used.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
SELECT Suppliers.[Supplier Name] AS Publisher, [Software Details].Vendor, Max([Software Details].ID) AS MaxOfID
FROM Suppliers RIGHT JOIN
     [Software Details]
     ON Suppliers.ID = [Software Details].Publisher
GROUP BY Suppliers.[Supplier Name], [Software Details].Vendor;
```

Here's a

[image: sample of results].

As you can see, I'm using the ID field as a way to identify the latest entry for each publisher/vendor combination; however, I only want to see the latest vendor for each publisher.

For example, the row that should be returned for Adobe Systems, Inc. is:

```
Publisher                 Vendor      MaxOfID
 Adobe Systems, Inc.       CDW-G       1357
```

I can't figure it out. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause with a subquery only to only select the highest IDs:

```
SELECT Suppliers.[Supplier Name] AS Publisher,
       [Software Details].Vendor,
       [Software Details].ID AS MaxOfID
FROM Suppliers
RIGHT JOIN [Software Details] ON Suppliers.ID = [Software Details].Publisher
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM Suppliers suppl
     RIGHT JOIN [Software Details] sd ON suppl.ID = sd.Publisher
     WHERE suppl.[Supplier Name] = Suppliers.[Supplier Name]
       AND sd.Vendor = [Software Details].Vendor
     HAVING Max(sd.ID) = [Software Details].ID)
```

Comment: When I run this, it's still showing duplicate vendors, but has eliminated all blank vendors. Here's a screenshot of the results for the Adobe example: https://imgur.com/a/e0oKN4f

Comment: Eh.. I thought you intended it this way. Remove `AND sd.Vendor = [Software Details].Vendor` to remove those results

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ranking Function and can get the expected result like this :

```
select * from (SELECT Suppliers.ID SuppliersID,[Software Details].ID 
[SoftwareDetailsID],
Suppliers.[Supplier Name],[Software Details].Vendor Vendor, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition 
by Suppliers.[Supplier Name] order by [Software Details].ID desc) as row
FROM Suppliers RIGHT JOIN [Software Details] ON Suppliers.ID = [Software 
Details].PublisherID
) A where row=1
```

Comment: Ranking functions are not available in MS Access. Your answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, `RIGHT JOIN` doesn't seem appropriate here.  Use `LEFT JOIN`.  Also table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Then, you can use a correlated query to get what you want:

```
SELECT s.[Supplier Name] AS Publisher, sd.Vendor, sd.ID AS MaxOfID
FROM Suppliers as s LEFT JOIN
     [Software Details] as sd
     ON s.ID = sd.Publisher
WHERE sd.ID = (SELECT MAX(sd2.ID)
               FROM [Software Details] as sd
               WHERE sd2.Publisher = sd.Publisher
              );
```